# ActionLink italics certain portion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I like to do something like the following in my MVC View:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("How do <i>This</i>", "Vtd", "Crs", new { Text= Html.Encode("How it works"}, null)
```

Notice how I want *This* to be in italics as a hyperlink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP MVC3 insert html tag inside actionlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718866/asp-mvc3-insert-html-tag-inside-actionlink)

Comment: Also see [Putting HTML inside Html.ActionLink(), plus No Link Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text)  and [Using HTML tags inside linkText of Html.ActionLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936681/using-html-tags-inside-linktext-of-html-actionlink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as `Html.ActionLink()` just render `<a href=".."></a>` tag maby that's not the best way to achive your goal.

I belive in your case it's better to use `Url.Action()` helper like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Vtd", "Crs", new { Text= Html.Encode("How it works"}, null })">
    How do <i>This</i>
</a>
```